# Is it possible to load different property files to use in the jsp with Spring messages?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, properties

I've different messages.properties files used for normal messages in my jsps, and also some other property files used in my java code.

One of this file is configured with some property to call a webservice, as the address, port and stuff like that. Let's call it `service.properties`.

One of my jsp has to call this service and I have to map the form with some information, like the action and the parameters. Right now I've written down these informations right in the jsp, but I find this not really nice, I would like to keep all the information coupled toghether inside the `service.properties`.

I'm looking for something to change the

```
<spring:message code="service.action.form"/>
```

to a customizable thing, to use not the messages but a specified property file

```
<spring:messageservice code="service.action.form" />
```

and move the information from the messages.properties to the service.properties

I don't know if this is possible, but I'm open to different options! Thanks.

Comment: The spring message tag is used to output internationalized messages from resource bundles. If all you want is configurable properties, load the file in your controller, and make its content available as a bean to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

Move your service related properties to file service.properties and then specify the path `/WEB-INF/<properties folder path>/service` in the basenames properties of bean `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` declared in your configuration xml file. And then you can just access that message with `<spring:message code='your.code'/>`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Ok, I did it, thanks. I just had to add a line to my ResourceBundleMessageSource already specified, but you gave me an hint. Thanks.